# How to avoid both tolls and highways for Restrictions in Google Directions API?

Tags: geolocation, google-api, google-directions-api

[Google Directions API](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/directions/#Restrictions) allows us to *attempt to* avoid tolls by supplying the argument `&avoid=tolls`.

Also, we can *attempt to* avoid highways by supplying the argument `&avoid=highways`.

I was wondering how do I supply the arguments for avoiding both tolls and highways?

Is it `&avoid=tolls|highways` or `&avoid=tolls,highways` ?

Comment: Have you *tried* either?

Comment: @RowlandShaw yep, but the returned results are the same no matter what I put. The guys at http://groups.google.com/group/google-maps-api-web-services/browse_thread/thread/7dff69e69066845c are also ignoring this question..

Comment: There's a difference between ignoring and not knowing the answer (as it doesn't appear to be documented)

Comment: Well, I can't construct a route (mentally) where there are alternates avoiding tolls and highways; all the tolls I know of are either on highways (so avoiding highways avoids the tolls) or are in such small locations that you wouldn't need to be avoiding highways as well.

Comment: @RowlandShaw Well that doesn't mean the documentation should be quiet about this. For example, if there's no info we don't even know if it's illegal to put in a `&avoid=tolls|highways`. Btw why did you vote to close?

Comment: You are right that the valid values should be documented by the vendor of the API (i.e. Google); it may be that the valid values are documented, and the option to avoid both is not supported by them. This is not the sort of thing that an outsider from Google could categorically state. You could do your own analysis (find a route that has an option that avoids tolls, but would normally use them, then check is avoiding highways and tolls still avoids it; repeat for a highway/avoidable highway route; but as it is not documented, don't rely on the implementation remaining fixed)

Comment: Any success with this question ?

Comment: @Beloru not at all. None is able to help.

Comment: @Belorus remember to post the answer if you have it!

Answer (score 2):

&avoid=tolls|highways

Search for "avoid=tolls|highways|ferries" on:
https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/directions/

Comment: It might be documented, but it doesn't work...

Answer (score 1):

I'm stuck on the "attempt to" avoid highways and tolls too. The docs clearly state "Note: the addition of restrictions does not preclude routes that include the restricted feature; it simply biases the result to more favorable routes"...so favorable = ignored arguments.

You can pass in both arguments...http://maps.google.com/maps/api/directions/xml?alternatives=true&units=imperial&avoid=tolls&avoid=highways...

Here's a link to the latest docs....
https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/directions/

Comment: Even the maps api linked in the answer doesn't do the job. You can verify by:

https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/directions/json?origin=58.6739164,14.9656690&destination=58.657812,14.958812&mode=walking&alternatives=true&avoid=highways&key=<Your_API_Key>

It does give the path which goes through Highway 50

Answer (score 1):

I ran into the same issue, so I did some tests and it **appears** as if `&avoid=tolls|highways` is the correct usage.

Going from Portland, OR to San Francisco, CA has tolls and highways. If you go to maps.google.com and route between the two, selecting different options, you find that Google gives you the same route for avoiding highways as avoiding highways and tolls.

When doing an API request `&avoid=tolls|highways` results in the same as `&avoid=highways|tolls`.

`&avoid=tolls,highways` results in not avoiding either.

`&avoid=tolls&avoid=highways` results in only avoiding tolls.

This all leads me to infer that Google must be reading both variables when you pass them with a `|`. however, avoiding tolls and highways often results in the same directions as just avoiding highways.

Answer (score 1):

Currently there seems to be a bug in the Google Directions API (not the client library). Multiple restrictions are not identified, e.g.`&avoid=highways|tolls` does not work but single do `&avoid=highways` and `&avoid=tolls`.

See answer:
https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/maps/WSp_qn6ou6I

I've opened a bug ticket for this on the Directions API bug tracker as there was none there already
https://code.google.com/p/gmaps-api-issues/issues/detail?id=10696