# Google Maps SDK avoid highways and tolls (iOS)

Tags: ios, swift, google-maps, google-places-api

I've read the documentations for both [android](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-api/intents#launch_turn-by-turn_navigation) and [iOS](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/ios-sdk/urlscheme) but only I can't find but I cant manage to make google maps avoid either tolls or highways, this is my current code (and `&avoid=tfh` does not work on iOS for me). Are there any way to avoid highways and tolls in the documentation?

```
        let ONE = getText("address")
        let TWO = getText("address2")

        Alamofire.request(.GET, "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/directions/json?language=sv&origin=\(ONE)&destination=\(TWO)&mode=drive&avoid=tfh", parameters: ["foo": "bar"])
            .responseJSON { response in...
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can see in this video: [Maps Shortcuts: Directions and the Google Maps iOS SDK](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=AdV7bCWuDYg) on how to load and display information from the Directions web service in your app. You can read in this [documentation](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/directions/intro#RequestParameters) the `avoid` parameter which indicates that the calculated route(s) should avoid the indicated features. It supports the following arguments:

- `tolls` indicates that the calculated route should avoid toll roads/bridges.
- `highways` indicates that the calculated route should avoid highways.

Check this related thread:

- [How to avoid both tolls and highways for Restrictions in Google Directions API?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8867122/how-to-avoid-both-tolls-and-highways-for-restrictions-in-google-directions-api)

Hope this helps!